# Error when using JSON to initialize TextButton (Libgdx)

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

I'm trying to initize a `TextButton` by giving it a JSON file which contains the style of the button, however I keep getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing LabelStyle font.

After researching what the error was about, it seems that this message shows up when you forget to include a font as part of the `TextButtonStyle`, however i do include that in my JSON file, so i don't know why it keeps showing.

Here's my json file

```
{

    "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color":{
    "golden":{"r":255,"g":215,"b":0,"a":1}

    },
    "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
      "arcade": {"file": "arcade.fnt"}

    },

    "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
            "default": {
                    "font": arcade,
                    "fontColor": golden
            }
    },

    "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle": {
            "buttonstyle1": {

                    "up": "unpressedtextbutton",
                    "down": "pressedtextbutton",
                    "font": arcade
    }
    }
}
```

and in the code I initialize the button like this:

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("buttonstyles.json"),new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("uistuff.atlas")));
myTextButton = new TextButton("text of the button",skin,"buttonstyle1")
```

My theory is that somehow it is not reading the font file "arcade.fnt", i'm assuming that the directory it reads the files from is the assets folder, and that's where my "arcade.fnt" file is located.

Comment: Try putting arcade in quotes, i.e. `"font": "arcade"`

Comment: I think you should use `{"file": "assets/arcade.fnt"}` in your JOSN file

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz if i write the directory that way i get "Font file not found: assets/arcade.fnt"

Comment: I think this is only for desktop apps

Comment: The pointer bases itself on the assets folder. calling /arcade.fnt (probably withoit the `/` as well) is enough

Answer (score 0):

i'm sorry it seems like i made a stupid mistake. Since i declared the font in the JSON file, i erased the font i was previously using in the code to define the button styles, and there was a usage of that font later for a label style, so, it was found to be null and it gave the error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it working like this? The official [uiskin.json](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json) does it like this:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
  default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
}
```

No quotes are needed at all not even for the font.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { 
  default-font: { file: default.fnt } 
},
```

Might not be proper JSON but libgdx has it's own lightweight JSON style.